# I Want to Annotate a Bar with a Value in PineScript. Can that be done?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to annotate a bar or an indicator with a value like open, high, low, close etc.  Is there a way to do that with PineScript?  Here is an example from another charting software of what I want to attempt to do.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsSjr.png)

I can't find a way in the reference manual to do anything other than showing a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [labels](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html) for that.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_none, text="x=" + tostring(bar_index) + "\ny=" + tostring(high))
```

[image]